# how to validate multiselect dropdown list in yii

Tags: yii

Hi all i need validate  multiselect  dropdown list in yii

please help me immediately my code like

```html
<select size="5" name="sampleMut[]" multiple="multiple" id="sampleMut">

 <option value="41" >41</option>
  <option value="48" >48</option>
  <option value="65" >65</option>
  <option value="102" >102</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this you can use the control (ctrl) button to select multiple options.
If you use dropdown with check box you can get the result.

In bootstrap:

Bootstrap Multiselect - http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

In terms of appearance, you may have to use CSS to get the styling you want.